# Embedding of Galois Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I am trying to prove the following:

> Let $E/k$ be a splitting field of $f(x)\in k[x]$ with Galois group $G=\operatorname{Gal}(E/k)$. Prove that if $k^*/k$ is an extension field and $E^*$ is a splitting field of $f(x)$ over $k^*$, then $\sigma\mapsto\sigma|E$ is an injective homomorphism $\operatorname{Gal}(E^*/k^*)\to\operatorname{Gal}(E/k)$.

I have two questions:

1) Is it necessary that $E\subset E^*$? Since $E^*$ is a splitting field over $k^*$ and we don't know how $k^*$ is constructed from $k$, I think the answer is no, but I do believe that there should be some embedding from $E$ to $E^*$. Am I right?

2) Assume that somehow we can identify $E$ as a subfield of $E^*$. I can prove that $\sigma\mapsto\sigma|E$ is well-defined and is a group homomorphism. How should I prove that it is injective? I think it would be nice if we can write $E=k(z_1,\cdots,z_n)$ and $E^*=k^*(z_1,\cdots,z_n)$ where $z_1,\cdots,z_n$ are roots of $f(x)$, but can we do that? It is certainly true that $E=k(z_1,\cdots,z_n)$, but I am not sure if $E^*$ can be constructed in the same way as adjoining $z_1,\cdots, z_n$. If it is true, then $\sigma|E=1_E$ implies that $\sigma$ fixes $k^*$ and $z_1,\cdots,z_n$ and hence fixes $E^*$.

Any help?

Comment: Your suspicion 1 is well founded. It may be a tacit assumption that everything takes place inside a fixed extension $\Omega$ of $k$. In that case the splitting field of $f$ over $k$ is unique - not just unique up to isomorphism. Without such a $\Omega$ in the background you first need to do some identifications for it to make sense to restrict $\sigma$ to $E$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Should $\Omega$ be an algebraic closure of $E$? I am not sure because I have not learned it yet.

Comment: $\Omega$ should definitely be algebraically closed. This time an algebraic closure of $k$ would suffice. On another occasion you may want $\Omega$ to also have as many independent transcendental elements as you need (like infinitely many). Just to be sure that you have elbow room to do whatever you need :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you so much! I am just wondering why no one tell me about this or no textbooks say something about it until I get confused and you tell me this. ;)

Comment: Hard to say, really. It may well be that this is explained in an intro to this section. Some other text may be working under the assumption that everything takes place inside the field of complex numbers. It should be mentioned/explained at some point. A logical point is shortly after proving the uniqueness of the splitting field up to isomorphism. After that an exercise asking you to show that without loss of generality we can assume that when $k\subset k^*$ the splitting field over $k$ is also a subfield of the splitting field of $k^*$.

Comment: That exercise is not very tough. Awllower essentially did it: you construct the splitting field over $k^*$, and then work inside that. No need for any fields like $\Omega$, if you do it that way! In some algebraic geometry texts they work with $\Omega$. +1 to you was there for observing that this is a problem. Well done! It can be dealt with in many ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, from the definitions, if $E=k(z_1,\cdots,z_n),$ where these $z_i$ are all the roots of $f,$ then $E^*$ is isomorphic to $k^*(z_1,\cdots,z_n).$ So there is a natural embedding $E\hookrightarrow E^*.$ Hence we might view $E$ as a subfield of $E^*.$
Finally, if $\sigma, \sigma'\in\text{Gal}(E^*/k^*)$ with $\sigma\mid_E=\sigma'\mid_{E},$ then $\sigma$ and $\sigma'$ agree on all roots of $f(x).$ Since $E^*$ is generated over $k^*$ by the roots of $f(x),$ and as every element of $\text{Gal}(E^*/k^*)$ must fix $k^*,$ it follows that $\sigma$ and $\sigma'$ agree on each element of $E^*.$ This shows that $\sigma=\sigma'.$
Therefore we have shown that the homomorphism in question is injective.
Hope this helps.
**P.S.**
**I.**
We can also define the splitting field of a polynomial over a field as the smallest field extension in which the polynomial splits completely, up to isomorphisms. Then we find that, as $E^*$ is the splitting field of $f$ over $k^*,$ it is a field containing $k$ in which $f$ splits completely, thus it follows that $E\subset E^*.$
Notice that "the" splitting field of a polynomial over a field is unique up to isomorphisms.

> To show that the splitting field is unique up to isomorphisms, we might use the isomorphism extension theorem to construct the required isomorphism.

**II.**
As to what $k^*(z_1,\cdots,z_n)$ means, recall how we construct $k(z)$ for an algebraic element $z:$ let $g$ be the minimal polynomial of $z$ over $k,$ and then we shall have $k(z)\cong k[x]/(g(x)).$
Hope this clarifies some doubts.

Comment: Thanks, but I still have some confusion. Let us consider both $E/k$ and $E'/k$ are splitting fields of $f(x)$. Although $E$ is isomorphic to $E'$, they are literally not the same set. So, what if $k^*$ contains some roots of $f(x)$ in $E'$? In this case, $k^*$ does not contain all the roots of $f(x)$ in $E$. So, how can you simply say that $E^*$ contains all the roots of $f(x)$? I am not sure if I make my confusion easily understood.

Comment: Besides, we can write $E=k(z_1,\cdots,z_n)$ where $z_1,\cdots,z_n$ are roots and live in some splitting field of $f(x)$. But, $\sigma'$, in your notation, does not have to fix $z_1,\cdots, z_n$ and perhaps fixes some other $z_1',\cdots,z_n'$ of $f(x)$ in some other splitting field $E'$. If $E$ and $E'$ are splitting field of $f(x)$ over the same field $k$, I would say $E$ are $E'$ are isormophic, so I have nothing to worry about. But, $E^*$ is a splitting field over $k^*$. As I said in the post, we don't know how $k^*$ is constructed from $k$, so I am not sure if $E^*=k^*(z_1,\cdots,z_n)$.

Comment: $E$ is not necessarily isomorphic to $E^*,$ as they are splitting fields of the same polynomial over different fields. I am saying that $E^*$ is the splitting field of $f$ over $k^*,$ so must contain the roots of $f.$ Is there a question? And I don't see what your second question is? I didn't say that $\sigma'$ fixes $E,$ just that it agrees with $\sigma$ on $E,$ and hence, equivalently, on every element of $E.$

Comment: Suppose $X=\{z_1,\cdots,z_n\}\subset E$ are roots of $f(x)$. It is possible that $Y=\{z_1',\cdots,z_n'\}\subset E^*$ are also roots of $f(x)$ and $Y\neq X$. So, how can you simply say $E^*$ contains all the roots of $f(x)$? What roots? You are blindly assuming that $X=Y$.

Comment: Similarly, the generators of $E$ over $k$ and the generators of $E^*$ over $k^*$ need not be the same. You are again blind assuming that $E=k(z_1,\cdots,z_n)$ and $E^*=k^*(z_1,\cdots,z_n)$.

Comment: Alright, but we have an isomorphism $E^*\cong k^*(z_1,\cdots,z_n),$ and then this gives us an embeding of $E$ into $E^*.$ In any case, we can choose $E$ and $E^*$ to lie in the same algebraic closure, and then everything is fine. In effect, an isomorphism does not affect the argument here, right? And thanks for reminding me of this issue.

Comment: Could you please show me how to construct an isomorphism $E^*\cong k^*(z_1,\cdots,z_n)$? If you can put it in your answer, I will accept it. BTW, your last comment helps!

Comment: BTW, how do you make sense of $k^*(z_1,\cdots,z_n)$ if $z_1,\cdots,z_n$ does not lie in some extension field of $k^*$? Actually, $z_1,\cdots,z_n\in E$. Now, I am wondering if an algebraic closure must be involved here to solve the issue? I have not learned algebraic closure yet, so I am not sure.

Comment: I made an edit; if there is still a dearth of explanations, just inform me. :)